# Finding how many times df['attacker_king'] and df['defender_king'] fought

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset

I have an assignment where I need to represent data from a dataset. I chose this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/mylesoneill/game-of-thrones
I am trying to find how many times Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon attacked Robb Stark.

```
df = pd.read_csv('battles.csv') 
starkWar = 0
for x in df:
    if (df.attacker_king == 'Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon') and 
       (df.defender_king ==  'Robb Stark'):
        starkWar + 1
```

I have tried using `&` instead of `and`, and I have tried doing:

```
df['attacker_king'] == 'Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon'
if df[(df['attacker_king'] == 'Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon') & (df['defender_king'] == 'Robb Stark')]:
```

instead of the way I currently have it. All of these give me this error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. 
Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have also tried this

Comment: a couple things. first, you'll want `starkWar += 1`. Secondly, is each row in your csv an attack and defender name? can you give maybe 5-10 rows of what battles.csv looks like?

Comment: @chitown88 you can find the battles.csv here https://www.kaggle.com/mylesoneill/game-of-thrones#battles.csv 
I don't know how to cleanly display the data so I thought a link would work better

Comment: if it works out for you, be sure to accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter the dataframe to find the rows where attacker is Joffrey and defender is Stark. Then just get the length of that dataframe. Would be quicker than having it iterate row by row.

```
starkWar = len(df.loc[(df['attacker_king'] == 'Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon') & (df['defender_king'] ==  'Robb Stark')])
```

but if you use your original code and iterate by rows (which is viable option too if it's not a huge amount of rows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('battles.csv') 
starkWar = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['attacker_king'] == 'Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon') and row['defender_king'] ==  'Robb Stark'):
    starkWar += 1

print (starkWar)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with df.loc before this is very useful